# bootstrap overiding with custom.css

Tags: css, django, overriding

I am using django and trying to override base.html that is calling the default bootstrap.min.css with a custom.css like this:

base.html:

```
<body id="bootstrap-overrides">
```

custom.css:

```
#bootstrap-overrides body {
    color: blue;
}

#bootstrap-overrides h1 {
    color: green;
}

#bootstrap-overrides p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

however, nothing really changes. Is it a routing problem in django?

Comment: Are you including the override stylesheet AFTER the bootstrap stylesheet? Is your custom stylesheet cached - do you have the latest version?  Do any of the above styles work or is it just the first style that is broken?  Have you inspected the body tag to ensure the id is being applied?

Comment: 1: yes, 2: yes 3: all is broken, 4: not sure, have to check

Comment: ok, I think it is a chache problem, safari is pretty hard when it comes to reload cache free pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
body#bootstrap-overrides {...}
```

If you want to try if your CSS file is working

```
body {
 background:red !important;
}
```

Comment: nothing of the above works. maybe there is something wrong with the css file, since background:red !important; didn't change anything.

Comment: You can use CTRL + F5 to refresh without cache :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
#bootstrap-overrides body {
color: blue;
```

}

with:

```
#bootstrap-overrides {
color: blue;
```

}

or:

```
body {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: still nothing. custom.css is loaded but it doesn't seem to do anything